# CheckMark Button in a table cell is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

CheckMark Button in a UItable cell is not working Thanks in advance  ,CheckMark Button in a table cell is not working

```
self.btn_acceptCheckmark = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250 , 25, 20, 20)];
        [self.btn_acceptCheckmark setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmarknormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btn_acceptCheckmark addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckMarkaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.btn_acceptCheckmark setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        self.btn_acceptCheckmark.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

cellforrowattindexpath:
Table view indexpath=4

```
else if (indexPath.section == 4){

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            lbl_offerertittle.text = @"Offerers";
            [cell addSubview:self.btn_acceptCheckmark];
            self.btn_acceptCheckmark.hidden=YES;

    }

        if ([[offersAsset valueForKey:@"offers"] isEqualToString:@"No listing"]) {
            lbl_offererName.text = @"No offers available!";
            lbl_offererName.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        }
        else {

              self.btn_acceptCheckmark.hidden=NO;
            lbl_offererCount.text = @"";
```

Checkmark Button action Method

```
-(IBAction)CheckMarkaction:(id)sender {

    if (self.btn_acceptCheckmark.isSelected==YES)
    {

    [self.btn_acceptCheckmark  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmarkactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   /// self.btn_acceptCheckmark .backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.btn_acceptCheckmark setSelected:NO];
        [self.tbl reloadData];


    }else if (self.btn_acceptCheckmark.isSelected==NO)
    {

        [self.btn_acceptCheckmark  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmarkactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //self.btn_acceptCheckmark .backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        [self.btn_acceptCheckmark setSelected:YES];
         [self.tbl reloadData];


    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the first line of `CheckMarkaction`. Click the button, and see if it goes into this method.

Comment: If there's more than one cell that has this button, there's definitely a problem, since there's only one `self.btn_acceptCheckmark` but you tried to add it to different cells.

Comment: Please define "not working".  What is the desired behaviour?  What is happening?  As @Hampotato suggests, your approach won't work if more than one cell requires a checkmark - This would probably be better handled by a specific UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: ya i have morethan one cell Like two cells

Comment: can any one tell me what to do ? Now

Comment: can any one tell me the solutation for this @Hampotato

Comment: The checkmark button showing there...but touch event not working right ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are getting checkmark button at least.You can use following code to toggle the image of button in UITableViewCell.It is working for me. For table view cell i guess you must get index path also.

```
- (void)selectDistance: (UIButton *)button event:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:
                              [[[event touchesForView:button] anyObject]
                               locationInView:self.table]];
    if (button.selected) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxoff-5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setSelected:NO];
    }else{
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxon-5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setSelected:YES];
 }
```

Comment: (void)selectDistance: (UIButton *)button event:(UIEvent *)event{ this method its self not calling

Comment: what have you set in initWithStyle:..?
 [self.btn_acceptCheckmark addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDistance:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: yes i have already given UIControlEventTouchUpInside but no use

Comment: try to set self.btn_acceptCheckmark.userInteractionEnabled=YES
Are you sure you have added button inside properly